# laravel-vue-spa: using laravel-snappy : how to properly view/stream the pdf

Tags: laravel, vue.js, wkhtmltopdf

[image]

my controller

```
    public function test(Request $request)
    {
        $per_day = Payment::per_day(Request::input('start'),Request::input('end'));
        $per_day = $per_day[0];
        $cash = $per_day->cash;
        $gcash = $per_day->gcash;
        $credit = $per_day->credit;
        $admin = Admin::first();
        
        $start_date = strtotime(Request::input('start'));
        $end_date = strtotime(Request::input('end'));

        $pdf = \App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');
        $pdf->loadView('pdf.sales_summary', array(
            'admin' => $admin,
            'per_day' => $per_day,
            'cash' => $cash,
            'gcash' => $gcash,
            'credit' => $credit,
            'start_date' => $start_date,
            'end_date' => $end_date,
            ))->setPaper('legal')->setOrientation('landscape')->save('12s.pdf');

        return $pdf->inline();
    }
```

How can I properly view/stream a pdf file using Laravel and Vue : using laravel-snappy?